# Fitting Model Parameters To Histogram Data in R

Tags: r, histogram, modeling, probability-density

So I've got a data set that I want to parameterise but it is not a Gaussian distribution so I can't parameterise it in terms of it's mean and standard deviation.  I want to fit a distribution function with a set of parameters and extract the values of the parameters (eg. a and b) that give the best fit.  I want to do this exactly the same as the

```
   lm(y~f(x;a,b))
```

except that I don't have a y, I have a distribution of different x values.

Here's an example.  If I assume that the data follows a Gumbel, double exponential, distribution

```
f(x;u,b) = 1/b exp-(z + exp-(z)) [where z = (x-u)/b]:

   #library(QRM)
   #library(ggplot2)
   rg <- rGumbel(1000) #default parameters are 0 and 1 for u and b
   #then plot it's distribution
   qplot(rg)
   #should give a nice skewed distribution
```

If I assume that I don't know the distribution parameters and I want to perform a best fit of the probability density function to the observed frequency data, how do I go about showing that the best fit is (in this test case), u = 0 and b = 1?

I don't want code that simply maps the function onto the plot graphically, although that would be a nice aside.  I want a method that I can repeatedly use to extract variables from the function to compare to others.  GGPlot / qplot was used as it quickly shows the distribution for anyone wanting to test the code.  I prefer to use it but I can use other packages if they are easier.

Note:  This seems to me like a really obvious thing to have been asked before but I can't find one that relates to histogram data (which again seems strange) so if there's another tutorial I'd really like to see it.

Comment: I don't think `lm` is going to help. Are you familiar with `fitdistr` in the MASS package or the corresponding function in the fitdistrplus package? In fact it would seem to me that you need education on distribution fitting, for which SO in not on-topic. Perhaps doing some reading and posting a few questions on CrossValidated.com might help bring you up to speed.

Comment: thanks, i'll go over there and have a look.